# WebDriver: explicitly wait doesn`t work by click to element

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver, nunit

My code with implicitly wait works well. But I read  information about waits and understood, that I need using explicitly wait in my projects. That`s why I am trying implement my test project with it. 
When step of my alhorithm equel click to button, I have error : http://joxi.ru/BA0GMyDhnY0n2y
Please, help me with it.

Base class:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System;
using LinkedinAddContacts.Pages;
using LinkedinAddContacts.TestData;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace LinkedinAddContacts
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class TestClass
    {
        private IWebDriver webDriver;
        private WebDriverWait waitDriver;

        [SetUp]
        public void InitializeBrowser()
        {
            webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
            waitDriver = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
            webDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            webDriver.Manage().Timeouts().PageLoad =  TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
            webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.linkedin.com/");
        }
        [Test]
        public void TestMethod()
        {
            Authorization authorizationData = new Authorization();
            StartPage objStartPage = new StartPage(waitDriver);
            NetworkPage objNetworkPage = new NetworkPage(waitDriver);

            objStartPage.EntrySystem(authorizationData);
            objNetworkPage.ConnectPeople();
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void CloseBrowser()
        {
            webDriver.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Secondary class:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using LinkedinAddContacts.TestData;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace LinkedinAddContacts.Pages
{
    public class StartPage
    {
      //  private IWebDriver webDriver;
        private WebDriverWait waitDriver;
        #region Objects

        public StartPage(WebDriverWait waitDriver)
        {
            this.waitDriver = waitDriver;
        }

        private IWebElement EmailInput
        {
            get
            {
                return waitDriver.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Name("session_key")));
                //return webDriver.FindElement(By.Name("session_key"));
            }
        }

        private IWebElement PasswordInput
        {
            get
            {
                return waitDriver.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Name("session_password")));
               // return webDriver.FindElement(By.Name("session_password"));
            }
        }

        private IWebElement LoginButton
        {
            get
            {
                return waitDriver.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Name("login-submit")));
                //return webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("login-submit"));
            }
        }

        private IWebElement RegistrationForm
        {
            get
            {
                return waitDriver.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Id("regForm")));
            //    return webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("regForm"));
            }
        }
        #endregion
        #region Methods  
        public void CloseRegistrationForm()
        {
            IJavaScriptExecutor js = waitDriver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
            js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById('regForm').style.display = 'none';");
            //  ((IJavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("scroll(0,400)");

        }


        public void EntrySystem(Authorization authorizationData)
        {
           // CloseRegistrationForm();
            EmailInput.SendKeys(authorizationData.Email);
            PasswordInput.SendKeys(authorizationData.Password);
            LoginButton.Click();
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

Error there:

```
 public void EntrySystem(Authorization authorizationData)
    {
       // CloseRegistrationForm();
        EmailInput.SendKeys(authorizationData.Email);
        PasswordInput.SendKeys(authorizationData.Password);
        LoginButton.Click();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When I understand it properly your code crashes at this line:

```
return waitDriver.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.Name("login-submit")));
```

Now, taking a look at the startpage of linkedIn reveals that the login-submit button doesn't have a name attribute defined, but you can use it's id instead.

```
<input tabindex="1" id="login-submit" class="login submit-button" type="submit" value="Einloggen">
```

So you should be using `By.id()` instead of `By.name()`.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to notice which web driver you use.

First of all, As @Robert says, its better to find by Id whenever it is available to you.

Second, I think LoginButton.Click() does not work. I had such a problem with chrome driver. When page scale(zooming) is changed, the Click method does not work properly, or clicks elsewhere on the page.

I recommend you to use SendKeys for any click action.
Just like this:

```
LoginButton.SendKeys(Keys.Enter);// or Keys.Return
```

Never ever use Click method

Comment: Thank you for advice ,  I take it to my skills. I didn`t talk about it anywhere.

Comment: Your advice  helps me in another project. I suffered with unclickable button more one week. Thanks again